# Is there a mathematical formula for the nearest-square function?

Tags: number-theory, functions, reference-request, square-numbers

Let $x$ be a positive integer.

Is there a mathematical formula for
$$f(x)=\text{nearest square to } x \text{ }(\text{in terms of } x)?$$

I tried searching for related questions in MSE and found this [one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/394917), but my inquiry is not covered there.

I also tried searching via Google and found this closely related question in [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45762619).

I used the search string "**nearest-square function**".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By virtue of the accepted answer in your linked question, you can take the [nearest integer function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/NearestIntegerFunction.html) of $\sqrt x$ and square it. However it may not be obvious (or seemingly *too obvious* to be true) so here are more details:

The nearest integer function (for $x \notin \{k+\frac12| k \in \mathbb Z\}$ to avoid ambiguities) is equal to $\left\lfloor x + \frac12\right\rfloor$. Fortunately for the square root, it is never an integer plus half. Hence we can also write

$$f(x) = \left\lfloor \sqrt x + \frac12\right\rfloor^2$$

To prove that this formula works, we consider the cases (where $n \in \mathbb N \cup \{0\}$):

Case 1: $n^2 \le x \le n^2+n < (n+\frac12)^2$

Case 2: $(n+\frac12)^2< n^2+n+1 \le x < (n+1)^2$

and we see that both cases work perfectly fine, given that $x$ is a positive integer.

Comment: @nicomezi I think I may have made a mistake, however. $x=12.3$ is a counterexample. I need to rethink this

Comment: @nicomezi Found the "fix" (there is no fix, since $x$ is an integer)

Comment: Ho my gosh, I am terrible at math and reading now. Tired of myself, like really. Nice work btw

Comment: @nicomezi It was I who suggested $12.3$ in the first place, I would say the fault/oversight is mine.

Comment: This is fantastic, @player3236.  Just what I needed!  Thanks. =)

Comment: It turns out that what I actually need is the nearest square to, but **larger than** $x$. Does your formula remain valid, @player3236?  Or will there be some adjustments?  Please advise.

Comment: Nearest square to, but larger... wouldn't that be rounding up, just like your linked question?

Comment: Okay got it!  Thanks again.  =)