# On the nearest-square function - Part 2 and the quantity $m^2 - p^k$ where $p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number

Tags: number-theory, inequality, conjectures, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

(Note:  This question has been cross-posted to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/q/376268).)

This question is an offshoot of this [earlier one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3902755) and this [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3555053).

Let $n = p^k m^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $p$ satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.

It was conjectured in [Dris (2008)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.1450) and [Dris (2012)](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html) that the inequality $p^k < m$ holds.

[Brown (2016)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01591) showed that the Dris Conjecture (that $p^k < m$) holds in many cases.

It is trivial to show that $m^2 - p^k \equiv 0 \pmod 4$.  This means that $m^2 - p^k = 4z$, where it is known that $4z \geq {10}^{375}$.  (See this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3556316) and [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3557070/28816), where the case $m < p^k$ is considered.)  Note that if $p^k < m$, then $$m^2 - p^k > m^2 - m = m(m - 1),$$
and that
$${10}^{1500} < n = p^k m^2 < m^3$$
where the lower bound for the magnitude of the odd perfect number $n$ is due to [Ochem and Rao (2012)](http://www.lirmm.fr/%7Eochem/opn/opn.pdf).  This results in a larger lower bound for $m^2 - p^k$.  Therefore, unconditionally, we have
$$m^2 - p^k \geq {10}^{375}.$$
We now endeavor to **disprove** the Dris Conjecture.

Consider the following sample proof argument:

**Theorem** If $n = p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number satisfying $m^2 - p^k = 8$, then $m < p^k$.

**Proof**

Let $p^k m^2$ be an odd perfect number satisfying $m^2 - p^k = 8$.

Then $$(m + 3)(m - 3) = m^2 - 9 = p^k - 1.$$

This implies that $(m + 3) \mid (p^k - 1)$, from which it follows that
$$m < m + 3 \leq p^k - 1 < p^k.$$
We therefore conclude that $m < p^k$.

**QED**

So now consider the equation $m^2 - p^k = 4z$.  Following our proof strategy, and the formula in the accepted answer to the first hyperlinked question, we have:

$$m^2 - \bigg(\lfloor{\sqrt{m^2 - p^k} + \frac{1}{2}}\rfloor\bigg)^2 = p^k + \Bigg(4z - \bigg(\lfloor{\sqrt{m^2 - p^k} + \frac{1}{2}}\rfloor\bigg)^2\Bigg).$$

> So the only remaining question now is whether it could be proved that
> $$\Bigg(4z - \bigg(\lfloor{\sqrt{m^2 - p^k} + \frac{1}{2}}\rfloor\bigg)^2\Bigg) = -y < 0$$
> for some **positive** integer $y$?

In other words, is it possible to prove that it is always the case that
$$\Bigg((m^2 - p^k) - \bigg(\lfloor{\sqrt{m^2 - p^k} + \frac{1}{2}}\rfloor\bigg)^2\Bigg) < 0,$$
if $n = p^k m^2$ is an odd perfect number with special prime $p$?

(Additionally, note that it is known that $m^2 - p^k$ is **not a square**, if $p^k m^2$ is an OPN with special prime $p$.  See this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3121498) and the [answer contained therein](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3122247/28816).)

If so, it would follow that
$$\Bigg(m + \lfloor{\sqrt{m^2 - p^k} + \frac{1}{2}}\rfloor\Bigg)\Bigg(m - \lfloor{\sqrt{m^2 - p^k} + \frac{1}{2}}\rfloor\Bigg) = p^k - y$$
which would imply that
$$\Bigg(m + \lfloor{\sqrt{m^2 - p^k} + \frac{1}{2}}\rfloor\Bigg) \mid (p^k - y)$$
from which it follows that
$$m < \Bigg(m + \lfloor{\sqrt{m^2 - p^k} + \frac{1}{2}}\rfloor\Bigg) \leq p^k - y < p^k.$$

**Update (November 11, 2020 - 10:21 PM Manila time)** Please check out the [recently posted answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3903086/28816) for a minor adjustment to the logic that should make the general proof argument work.

Comment: Are there any more restrictions on $p$ and $k$? Or can $p$ be any prime, and $k$ and $m$ any integers? I ask, because your sample proof doesn't use the fact that $p^km^2$ is perfect or odd.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, @Servaes!  $p$ is the special prime of the odd perfect number $n = p^k m^2$ satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.

Comment: You call it *'the'* special prime; does every odd perfect number have precisely one such prime divisor? Do you have any helpful results on these special primes? I ask because I know absolutely nothing abouth such numbers, only that it is very easy to construct examples without the restriction that $p^km^2$ is perfect. So it would be nice to know what restriction implies for $p$ and $m$.

Comment: @Servaes:  Yes, every odd perfect number (OPN) has exactly one (*special*) prime divisor $p$ occurring to an odd exponent $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.  There are lots of *results* on the special prime of an OPN, the most notable of which, in my opinion, is due to [Cohen and Sorli (2012)](http://emis.impa.br/EMIS/journals/INTEGERS/papers/a6self/a6self.pdf).  I just do not know whether Cohen and Sorli's results on the special prime of an OPN would be helpful for the purpose of resolving this question.

Comment: @Servaes:  Additionally, note that it is known that $m^2 - p^k$ is **not a square**, if $p^k m^2$ is an OPN with special prime $p$.  See this [MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3121498) and the [answer contained therein](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3122247/28816).

Comment: Note that $\lceil \sqrt{x}\rceil^2$ is not the smallest square larger than $x$. Take $x=1$.

Comment: That is fine, @mathlove.  I am sure that $m^2 - p^k$ is **not a square**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a proof that the smallest square larger than $m^2-p^k$ is not $m^2$, then your method does not work.

Otherwise, your method works.

Using your idea, one can prove that if $\lfloor\sqrt{4z}+1\rfloor\lt m$, then $m\lt p^k$.

*Proof* :

Subtracting $\lfloor\sqrt{4z}+1\rfloor^2$ which is the smallest square larger than $4z$ from the both sides of
$$m^2=p^k+4z$$
gives
$$m^2-\lfloor\sqrt{4z}+1\rfloor^2=p^k-\lfloor\sqrt{4z}+1\rfloor^2+4z$$
which can be written as
$$(m-\lfloor\sqrt{4z}+1\rfloor)(m+\lfloor\sqrt{4z}+1\rfloor)=p^k-\lfloor\sqrt{4z}+1\rfloor^2+4z\tag1$$

So, we can say that
$$m+\lfloor\sqrt{4z}+1\rfloor\mid p^k-\lfloor\sqrt{4z}+1\rfloor^2+4z\tag2$$

If $\lfloor\sqrt{4z}+1\rfloor\lt m$, then LHS of $(1)$ is positive, so RHS of $(1)$ is positive. So, we can say that$$(2)\implies m+\lfloor\sqrt{4z}+1\rfloor\le p^k-\lfloor\sqrt{4z}+1\rfloor^2+4z$$from which we can have$$m\lt m+\lfloor\sqrt{4z}+1\rfloor\le p^k-\lfloor\sqrt{4z}+1\rfloor^2+4z\lt p^k.\quad\blacksquare$$

---

If $m=\lfloor\sqrt{4z}+1\rfloor$, then letting $\sqrt{4z}=N+a$ where $N\in\mathbb Z$ and $0\le a\lt 1$, we have
$$p^k-m=(N+1)^2-(N+a)^2-N-1=(1-2a)N-a^2$$
whose sign depends on $a$ and $N$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @mathlove! I think it would always be possible to subtract the larger square that is nearest to a given value of $4z = m^2 - p^k$, hence $m < p^k$ is **always true**? (Please see other answer.)

Comment: @Arnie Bebita-Dris : I don't think so because $$m+\lfloor\sqrt{4z}+1\rfloor \mid p^k-\lfloor\sqrt{4z}+1\rfloor^2+4z\implies m+\lfloor\sqrt{4z}+1\rfloor\le p^k-\lfloor\sqrt{4z}+1\rfloor^2+4z$$ is true only when $p^k-\lfloor\sqrt{4z}+1\rfloor^2+4z$ is positive.

Comment: @Arnie Bebita-Dris : In your answer, you are assuming that $p^k-9$ is positive. In other words, you are considering only $p,k$ satisfying $p^k-9$ is positive.

Comment: As an extreme example, we have $m^2 - p^k = 48$. Subtracting the smallest square that is larger than $48$, we get $(m+7)(m-7)=m^2 - 49=p^k - 1$, from which we obtain $(m+7) \mid (p^k - 1)$ and consequently, $m < m+7 \leq p^k - 1 < p^k$.  **QED**

Comment: That $p^k - 9$ is indeed positive is automatic from $m^2 - p^k = 40$ since we have the lower bound $m^2 > {10}^{750}$ from the estimates $p^k < m^2$ (Dris, 2012) and ${10}^{1500} < n = p^k m^2$ (Ochem and Rao, 2012).

Comment: @Arnie Bebita-Dris : Ah, thanks for pointing it out. I think that if you can say that $p^k-\lfloor\sqrt{4z}+1\rfloor^2+4z$ is positive (which I don't know if true), then $m\lt p^k$ is always true. Note that $p^k-\lfloor\sqrt{4z}+1\rfloor^2+4z\gt 0$ is equivalent to $m\gt \lfloor \sqrt{4z}+1\rfloor$.

Comment: @Arnie Bebita-Dris : Thanks for your comment. I edited my answer.

Comment: @Arnie Bebita-Dris : Also, as your example $m^2-p^k=48$ where $z=12$, if $z$ satisfies $5-\lfloor\sqrt{4z}+1\rfloor^2+4z\gt 0$, then we can say $m\lt p^k$ since we have $p^k-\lfloor\sqrt{4z}+1\rfloor^2+4z\ge 5^1-\lfloor\sqrt{4z}+1\rfloor^2+4z\gt 0$. I think this is what you are trying to say, and what I didn't consider.

Comment: I still cannot seem to wrap my head around your argument. Since $m^2 - p^k$ is **not a square**, and since we can always subtract the smallest square larger than $4z=m^2 - p^k$ (from *both sides of the equation*), is it not the case that my argument holds up, @mathlove?

Comment: Besides, don't you think that the negation of your hypothesis ($m \leq \lfloor\sqrt{4z}+1\rfloor$) would result in some boundedness condition for odd perfect numbers?

Comment: @Arnie Bebita-Dris : I've rewritten my answer completely. Please see the answer from the top. The key point is that RHS of $(1)$ can be **negative**. Also, note that I'm **not** saying that it is not always true that $m\lt p^k$. What I'm saying is that, **using your idea**, when $m\le \sqrt{2z+\frac 12\lfloor\sqrt{4z}+1\rfloor^2}$ or $m=\lfloor\sqrt{4z}+1\rfloor$, it is not proven that $m\lt p^k$.

Comment: You can omit the equals sign in the inequality $m \geq p^k$ in your last sentence since it is known that $\gcd(p,m)=1$, @mathlove.

Comment: @Arnie Bebita-Dris : Thank you for pointing it out. I edited it.

Answer (score 0):

Let me illustrate what I have in mind for a small value of $z$, say $z=10$.

Then we have
$$m^2 - p^k = 4z = 40$$
$$m^2 - 49 = p^k - 9$$
$$(m+7)(m-7) = p^k - 9.$$
This implies that
$$(m+7) \mid (p^k - 9)$$
from which it follows that
$$m < m+7 \leq p^k - 9 < p^k.$$

Note that $49$ is **not** the nearest square to $40$ ($36$ is), but rather the **nearest square larger than $40$**.

With this minor adjustment in the logic, I would expect the general proof argument to work.